# Renaming fasta headers to bracketed text

Tags: regex, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a file with 250 fasta sequences. Right now, the they look like this:

```
>NP_041982.1 DNA polymerase [Enterobacteria phage T7]
```

I want to change the headers so they look like this:

```
>Enterobacteria phage T7
```

For each header, I only want what is in-between the brackets. I'm trying to do this through linux commands.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Try with sed: sed 's@^>[^\[]*\[\([^\]*\)]@>\1@g' file.fa

Comment: It says sed: -e expression #1, char 23: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS.

Comment: this is probably a bad idea since fasta spec and most parsers will assume the id is only up to the first whitespace.  So if you have more than 1 Enterobacteria some programs might drop some sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.fa contents

```
>Sequence One [Species 1]
actgtattagctaatcgatcagttacgattcga
tagctacgtacgtacgatcgatcagtcagctag
>Sequence Two [Species 2]
ttgtagctagctagctagctagctagctacgta
tgcatcgatcgattaatatcgcgccctaactcg
>Sequence Three
atgatagtctggtcatcgattcagtcagttcat
ttgcatgatctactagatcgatattagctagat
>Sequence Four [early bracket] text
tagctacgtacgatcgtacgatcgatcgtatat
gctagtcgactagctagctacgtacgtacgtaa
```

sed command:

```
sed 's@^>[^\[]*\[\([^\]*\)]$@>\1@g' file.fa
```

It looks a bit convoluted, but it means...
take any string of characters that matches the pattern of "a line that starts with >, followed by any number of characters besides [, followed by any number of characters besides ], followed by ]. Capture the string between the brackets, and replace the entire match with just the thing in the brackets.

prints the output

```
>Species 1
actgtattagctaatcgatcagttacgattcga
tagctacgtacgtacgatcgatcagtcagctag
>Species 2
ttgtagctagctagctagctagctagctacgta
tgcatcgatcgattaatatcgcgccctaactcg
>Sequence Three
atgatagtctggtcatcgattcagtcagttcat
ttgcatgatctactagatcgatattagctagat
>Sequence Four [early bracket] text
tagctacgtacgatcgtacgatcgatcgtatat
gctagtcgactagctagctacgtacgtacgtaa
```

the output can be saved to a new file with

```
sed 's@^>[^\[]*\[\([^\]*\)]$@>\1@g' file.fa > converted_filename.fa
```

Note that any headers without matches are printed as-is, and any lines that have characters after the final bracket will also be printed as-is. Might act odd if it encounters left brackets that are not closed on the same line. I'd recommend you double check that the new file has the same number of lines as the original.